# Returning SETOF record loses record type when called from another query

Tags: postgresql

I'm declaring a Postgres function that returns a setof records from a table that already exists.

```
create function foo_get(b bar)
returns setof foo as $$
  select foo.*
  from foo
  where foo.bar = b.id;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Which is a simplification of the actual function I wrote, but works as expected (it returns all the columns of `foo`, for all the records I wanted to find).

However, if I try to access those columns specifically in the following fashion, Postgres complains:

```
select wumbo.id from
(select foo(bar) from bar) as "wumbo";
```

And that results in saying wumbo does not have an `id` column, even though the `id` data comes back if I just ask for `select wumbo.*` rather than `select wumbo.id`.

I'm OK if I'm doing something against paradigm here (and I'm not surprised if I am), but I'd like to understand why. Does returning a `setof foo` not equal returning the full schema of my `foo` table? Is Postgres converting the record I return into an anonymous record without column types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting from a table with a single anonymous column that holds `foo` records. The `wumbo` table indeed doesn't have an `id` column. The following would work:

```
select (wumbo.column).id
from (select foo(bar) as column from bar) as wumbo;
```

However, what I would recommend is to use a lateral query instead:

```
select wumbo.id
from bar, foo(bar) as "wumbo";
```